# Windows typeperf and pound signs

Tags: windows

I'm currently trying to use [typeperf](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753182%28WS.10%29.aspx) to access some Windows performance counters.  Unfortunately, a few of the instances I'm trying to check are of the format `service#1`.

The command

```
 typeperf "\\server\Process(service#1)\Working Set Peak"
```

is unfortunately returning the data for `\\server\Process(service)\Working Set Peak` rather than the data for the instance `service#1`.  This holds true for *any* of the services that have pound signs in the counter string.  Does anyone know of a method to get around this problem?

Sample output:

```
I:\>typeperf -s server "\Process(service#1)\Working Set"

"(PDH-CSV 4.0)","\\server\Process(service)\Working Set"
"10/08/2009 09:37:29.070","1643274240.000000"
"10/08/2009 09:37:30.070","1643274240.000000"
"10/08/2009 09:37:31.070","1643274240.000000"

The command completed successfully.

I:\>typeperf -s server "\Process(service#2)\Working Set"

"(PDH-CSV 4.0)","\\server\Process(service)\Working Set"
"10/08/2009 09:37:39.273","1643274240.000000"
"10/08/2009 09:37:40.273","1643274240.000000"
"10/08/2009 09:37:41.273","1643274240.000000"
"10/08/2009 09:37:42.273","1643274240.000000"
"10/08/2009 09:37:43.273","1643274240.000000"

The command completed successfully.
```

I can confirm in PerfMon that the Working Set value "1643274240.000000" is incorrect for both `service#1` and `service#2`.

I am running Windows XP Service Pack 2, but a co-worker who is running Windows Server 2003 was having the same troubles.

Comment: I get different, but consistent, results for every pair (with and without `#1`) that I tried. Perhaps you could add sample results to your question. Also, in case it makes a difference, you should post which version of Windows.

Comment: Updated with sample output.

Comment: I thought a pound sign was £...

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, I'm having similar issues. However, my behavior is different.

For me, the # signs are recognized properly under Windows Server 2003 (SP2) and Vista. But I have the same issue with XP SP2.

An interesting thing to note as well, typeperf can seem to list or output the counters with # signs, it just can't seem to report them when you supply them as input, from the command line or a counter input file.

Perfmon can report them fine. I wonder why all this difference.

Too bad there is not enough typeperf users out there to get this resolved or looked into by Microsoft or others.